# jQuery inner zoom function (partially working)

Tags: javascript, jquery, prestashop

I've been trying to get a proper 'inner zoom' jQuery plugin to function on my webshop's category page. Because i'm limited in my skills, not every one of them seems to work as easy.

However, i've found one that met my needs;
- The image thumbnail and large image are the same link source, just a width/height readjusted
- The zoom appears inside the image's 'frame'
- No 'magnifying glass' type of zoom with like 40x40px, the entire picture needs to enlarge at once
- Short, simple code

It's regarding this plugin: http://www.jacklmoore.com/zoom/

It works fine, except it only works on **one image at a time (per page).** When I copy the same code more than once, it only works on the first image.

How do I get it so that it works an unlimited number of times? Or perhaps any other type of zoom plugin that meets my needs?

I hope someone can help me out.

Best,
Dave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it's explained on the plugin page, the zoom function can only be applied to images that are wrapped in some HTML tag. I think what you're trying to do is to apply the zoom function to a container that contains several images and therefore it only works for the first image.

What you could try to do is use the second code example, which should wrap the images and then apply the zoom function, but be careful so it doesn't break the styling:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('img')
    .wrap('<span style="display:inline-block"></span>')
    .css('display', 'block')
    .parent()
    .zoom();
});
```

If you could provide some code from your page which shows the images and their HTML containers, it would be easier to help you out with more specific jQuery code.

Comment: That seems to work, thanks!

However, it applies the plugin to **all** images on my page, can I make it so it only targets images within the class "center_block"?

Comment: Oh, think I found it: `$('.center_block img')`

Comment: Yeah, you would need to specify the selector, glad I could help :)